# Return nth-child number then add it to that link as a data attribute

Tags: jquery, function, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to use jQuery to return the child navigation elements relation to its sibling, and then add a data attribute to each sibling with the number that represents their order.

So if there are for siblings, the third sibling has data-link="3".

The order of the nav links are determined by the user in a CMS.

My current HTML structure is:

```
<nav>
    <a class="season-nav-link" href="#">1</a>
    <a class="season-nav-link" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="season-nav-link" href="#">3</a>
    <a class="season-nav-link" href="#">4</a>
</nav>
```

And my JS is:

```
$(function(){
    var ordernum = ($("nav.season-slider-nav a").index()+1);
    var orderlink = $("a.season-nav-link");
    $(orderlink).attr('data-info', ordernum);
});
```

Currently is returns with the data attribute in each link, but the value of each one is "1".

Answer (score 2):

this happen because you are only using the first element of the result of your first selector.

you probably want to iterate over all siblings and fill a list of values.

then iterate over the second selector results and fill accordingly

pseudo example:

```
$(function(){
    var ordernum = [];
    $("nav.season-slider-nav a").each(function(index, element){
         ordernum.push(index+1);
     });
    $("a.season-nav-link").each(function(index, element){
         $(element).attr('data-info', ordernum[index]);
    });
  });
```

Comment: I got some errors with this. this.index is not a function.

Comment: @MichaelHeimes just edited the answer. hope this works.

Comment: This gave me the error: ordernum.append is not a function.

Comment: back to this.index is not a function.

Comment: Now I got element.attr is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Pls use 'each' to access each element, since index can be obtained from 'each' itself, you can just write:

```
$(function(){
  $("nav a").each(function(index, elem) {
    $(elem).attr('data-info', index + 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: You are the MAN! SO simple and it works so well. I have a lot to learn with JS and jQuery. I hope to set enough time aside soon to study instead of just trying to manipulate snippets I find. Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually getting strange values returned. 13,14,15,16.

Comment: Guess there are many anchor (a) elements inside your nav (index is based on all elements). If you want to be more specific, you can add the class name or relavant selector in 'nav' or 'a': $("nav.className a.className").each(....